# Editing a link's name attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following links

```
<section class="col-sm-12 les_navigation">
   <a id="home" href="">Home</a>
    <a id="about" href="">About</a>
     <a id="resume" href="">Resume</a>
      <a id="portfolio" href="">Portfolio</a>
       <a id="blog" href="">Blog</a>
        <a id="contact_me" href=""></a>
   </section>
```

and the last link has a blank name attribute

```
<a id="contact_me" href=""></a>
```

I want to append the current width on every window resize with this code

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
var current_width = $('.les_body').width();
$('#contact_me').attr('name',current_width);
});
```

However,the new width is not appended.How can i fix this?.

Comment: you want to append current width to href attribute or want to add another attribute called 'name'?

Comment: I want to append current width to href with the id `#contact_me` .

Comment: change 'name' to 'href'. 'name' is nothing.

Comment: `name` is obsolete http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete Thanks @stefancarlton

Comment: This is not the `name` attribute you are referring, it is the `html`: `$('#contact_me').html(current_width);`

Comment: I see why html works but its a little disorienting to call one attribute html and the other attribute.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
var current_width = $('.les_body').width();
$('#contact_me').attr('href',current_width);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this mate,if u need to have the href replaced.You don't have an attribute named `name` in your `<a id="contact_me" href=""></a>`

```
    $( window ).resize(function() {
    var current_width = $('.les_body').width();
    $('#contact_me').attr('href',current_width);
```

//If u need the text replaced try

```
 // $('#contact_me').text(current_width);
```

// If you want to `append` that value to the href tag try.So if your `current href is contact` and width is `400` then your new `href` will be `contact400`

```
//    $('#contact_me')..attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + current_width);
});
```